# What does ‘put a heavy thumb on" mean?

Tags: phrases

More recently, I have come across a sentence in Los Angles Times, which says "A White House office dedicated to the issue, similar to the White House office focusing on climate change, would put a heavy thumb on the bureaucracy of government". I was wondering whether put a heavy thumb on means criticize. Thanks for help.

Comment: *Put a heavy thumb on X* is simply a modified version of ‘put a thumb on the scale’ which means *to unfairly benefit one party involved in an interaction* [[Wikitionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/thumb_on_the_scale)]. ‘Heavy’ is emphasising the expression here.

Comment: Thanks so much. I looked this phrase up in lots of dictionary but it has only one phrase " put a thumb on the scale" as you have mentioned in the previous answer. So, let me recap, A White House office would unfairly benefit one party involved in an interaction. Is that correct?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say that "put a heavy thumb on the bureaucracy of government" means "to unfairly benefit the bureaucracy of government"; rather it means to exert pressure or influence on something to bend it to your will. It may relate to the idiom "under the thumb", meaning under the control of someone. It may not be the correct use of an idiom but the author clearly means to say it will exert pressure or influence, or to bias by forcing the issue.

Comment: Yes. I think it makes sense now. A White House office would exert pressure on the bureaucracy of government.